# Angular google-maps not displayed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs

I'm creating an app in which I have a carpooling module. Now I want to display a map on which you'll be able to see carpoolers that are close to you. However, the map won't show..

I'm using a directive from

> http://nlaplante.github.io/angular-google-maps/

I've added the google-maps to my dependencies and the directive is replaced by a google map, but it doesn't show anything.

I've got this directive in my view:

```
<google-map center="center" 
        zoom="zoom" 
        markers="markers" 
        style="height: 400px; width: 100%; display: block;">
</google-map>
```

I have all the variables in my controller:

```
 $scope.center = {
        latitude: 45,
        longitude: -73
    };
    $scope.markers = [];
    $scope.zoom = 8;
```

When I open firebug, I get following error:

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [googleMap, markers] asking for new/isolated scope on: <google-map class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope" center="center" zoom="zoom" markers="markers" style="height: 400px; width: 100%; display: block;">
```

I've tried a lot of things and searched for solutions, but none fixed my problem. Is there anyone that can help?

Thanks in advance.
HS.

Comment: Pleases provide more details or a full code example

Answer (score 8):

I think you have two problems:

1. Markers

   `<google-map center="center" zoom="zoom" draggable="true">
           <markers models="markers" coords="'geometry'"></markers>
    </google-map>`

   Where 'geometry' is the property where you got the coordinates. If the markers are coordinates as themselves you can set coords="'self'"
2. Style: Don't need to set the map styles at the directive. Rather than that you need to specify a css style

   `.angular-google-map-container {
       height: 700px;
    }`

Answer (score 3):

In the error message there is `[googleMap, markers]` mentioned.

The new version requires to create a marker object inside of your google-map object and remove the directive from google-map.

Example:

```
<google-map center="center" 
    zoom="zoom" 
    markers="markers" 
    style="height: 400px; width: 100%; display: block;">

    <markers>
     <marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" coords="marker"></marker>
    </markers>

</google-map>
```

I hope this helps.